# git: revert all committed files in a directory to master

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a feature branch `feature-1-branch` created from master.
A lot of time as passed and I created a lot of commits on `feature-1-branch`.

Now I want to revert commit all changes in a specific directory, lets say `src/modules/feature-2` I made in branch `feature-1-branch` back to the state as they are in `master`.

Im sure this must be possible in git, just not sure how to do it!?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just checkout *src/modules/feature-2* directory from `feature-1` branch to `origin/master` branch.

```
$ git checkout feature-1-branch
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin/master src/modules/feature-2/
```

Now, You have identical *src/modules/feature-2* directory in both `master` and `feature-1-branch` branch.

Comment: oh fantastic, this works, didn't know you could checkout directories :) Thanks a lot sajib khan

Comment: btw, the changes where added already, so commit and push did the trick!

Comment: It would be a good idea to stash the changes, not to wipe out completely incase you need it in future.

Comment: @AnoopToffy - `"git: revert all committed files in a directory to master"`, here changes are already committed, unlike we can stash only uncommitted changes. - Also, we can back the changes simply by checkout the dir again to the last commit that has the changes (last commit before checkout first time)

Comment: Yea. you are right. we can stash only uncommitted changes.